# Filter DataTable without LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, .net-2.0

How can I filter a datatable without using LINQ?  I am currenlty using .NET 2.0; therefore, I am unable to use LINQ. I have a stored procedure that returns room/rate pairs.  I want to filter the datatable so it will select all the rates for a particular room, so essentially something like this:

```
SELECT Rates FROM TABLE1 WHERE Room = @Room.
```

Can I do this with a DataTable or is it better just to create another stored procedure to avoid using inline sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you CAN do it with [DataTable's Select method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx)

```
// if table is your DataTable
DataRow[] foundRows =table.Select("Room = " + roomName);
```

as for deciding IF you want to do it this way or if it's better to rewrite your stored procedure to accept a @room parameter, it depends:
if there aren't many total rows and if you're changing the selected room often then it might be better performance-wise to do it the way you're doing (keeping one total DataTable in memory and filtering it for different rooms)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the filter property of the default view, like this:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "SomeColumn > 0";    
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

You can also use the Select method too:

```
dt = dt.Select("SomeColumn > 0").CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

surely a stored procedure would be the way to go, consider that you can also have the parameter set to `NULL` in the stored so you ignore it when null or use it when provided with a value.

from the .NET side you can also select a subset of DataRows of a DataTable which satisfy a filter condition, something like this:

```
DataRow[] rows = myTable.Select("Room = '1'");
```

but as I said, server side filtering is better, less data moving in the network....